# how to get input data when go back in android

Tags: android, android-intent, keyevent

I am new to android development .
I've created an android application and I use an activity(first activity) to input some data . Then I use a button on it to go to another activity(second activity). When I press the back button on the device(at this time I am on second activity), I couldn't see any data on the first activity . I used an object(Bean) to store input data and I passed it to the second activity.

My question is how to reload that data to first activity ?
Any comment will be appreciated!.

This is the code in first activity to start second activity .

```
Intent intent=new intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Example",bean);
startActivity(intent);
```

Code for go to first activity

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
       final ExampleBean bean=(ExampleBean)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Example");
       if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
           Intent intent=new intent(this,FirstActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("Example",bean);
           startActivity(intent);
           return true; 
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event); 
   }
```

Comment: please provide your code in first activity and second activity

Comment: look at the updates of my question

Comment: you can remove the "Code for go to first activity" (delete the onKeyDown function).

Comment: Please explain the purpose .

Comment: for example, first activity is A, second activity is B.
From A you call B, then from B you call A then you will 2 activity A and it different

Comment: Simple, If U want ur data over there while click back button. 1) don't call again first activity from second. because if U press back automatically it will come to First activity. 2) Use Sharedpreferences .

Comment: @Ram23 :- Can you provide example for Sharedpreferences ?

Comment: If U google..... lot more Eg: u will get ... Still       http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FirstActivity, sending data to the SecondActivity:

```
// your button or trigger to start the second activity
int someNumber = 10;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY_SENDING_DATA", someNumber);
int requestCode = 1;
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

Important things here:

1. The key `KEY_SENDING_DATA` must be the same key used on SecondActivity to get the extra you're passing
2. `startActivityForResult` is what makes FirstActivity be expecting some result
3. The number `1` we're passing on `startActivityForResult` is a request code. We will use this request to get the data from SecondActivity into FirstActivity.

In SecondActivity, receiving data from FirstActivity:

```
// this would possibly go in onCreate, but could be anywhere
Intent extraIntent = getIntent();
int numberReceived = extraIntent.getIntExtra("KEY_SENDING_DATA", -1);
```

Note here the `-1`. This is the default value for this int in case we're not passing a number (usually when something goes wrong).

**Now, sending data back from SecondActivity to FirstActivity.**

In the SecondActivity:

```
// again, this would be inside of a button or some other trigger
Intent result = new Intent();
int myFinalResult = 101;
result.putExtra("KEY_FINAL_RESULT", myFinalResult);
setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
finish();
```

*Notice how this just closes the activity and makes no reference to the FirstActivity.*

And to receive it in the FirstActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        int result = data.getIntExtra("KEY_FINAL_RESULT", -1);

        // if you're receiving a serializable object
        MyCustomObject myObject = (MyCustomObject)data.getExtras().getSerializable("KEY_FINAL_RESULT");
    }
}
```

And that should do it.

Usually you set the keys to be static Strings and ints so you don't confused as to what you called, but that should be all.

Eduardo

Comment: According to your exploration how could I pass an object to first activity ?

Comment: That is a little bit trickier. The reason is because your object must implement Serializable or Parcelable first. You may want to research that by itself. To then send it is just easy. In `result.putExtra("KEY_FINAL_RESULT", myFinalResult);` the myFinalResult is your object.

Comment: how to apply above changes to onActivityResult() method ?

Comment: TooManyEduardos Best of luck .

Answer (score 2):

When you start a new activity the original activity goes into pause state.You should write code to load your data in onResume() of the original activity.
This will ensure that your data is loaded when you come back to the original activity from the new activity

Comment: Can you provide some examples ? I am still confused .

Comment: You need to add your code in the question.Then I can help you better

Comment: Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when navigating to new Activity, so that It opens up a new activity while your old activity still remains and your data is retained when you click the back button.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: :- Please wait couple of minutes

Comment: You can create an OnClick Listener for that button, you didn't post your full code so its hard to see the true picture

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.